# Equivalent of NSString.CreateNative() for NSData in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin

Is there an equivalent of NSString.CreateNative() for NSData when using Xamarin? I would like to get the NSData's pointer in IntPtr format so I can pass it to an external function. Using the Bytes field does not work and causes the program to hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Handle` of your NSData object:

```
var aNSDataObject = aNSDataObject.FromObject(new object());
var iAmAIntPtr = aNSDataObject.Handle;
```